# Angular not-global singleton service

Tags: angular

I know how to create a singleton service for my entire program to use (by declaring it in the app.module). But I would like to create a service that is only a singleton to all the components below it. So for example:

- Main 1

  - Service
  - Child 1.1

    - Child 1.1.1
  - Child 1.2
- Main 2

  - Child 2.1
  - Child 2.2

In this hierarchy, I would like `Service` to be a singleton that can only be used by Children 1.x, NOT by Main2 or Child2. Here is my service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class SharedService {
   ...
}
```

But MUST I import this service in `app.module`? If I import it in `app.module` then it is global, I don't want it to be global.

Comment: You can add it to the `providers` array of `Main 1`, this making it a single instance for that modue

Comment: You can create separate modules for both main 1 and 2. Import the service for both separately,  this way each should have their own instance of the service. Then can even implement lazy loading if you want to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what Angular's Hierarchical Dependency is all about.

A Component also has a `providers` array. You can add your service to that array. And then this Component and any of its child Component will share the same singleton.

So your Main1 will have a `RootComponent` in it. In it's `@Component` metadata, just add a `providers` array and specify the token for your Service there.

This is what it would look like in code:

```
@Component({
  ...,
  providers: [ SharedService ]
})
export class Main1Component { ... }
```

So now that you've done that, the `SharedService` will only be accessible by Main1, Child1.1, Child1.1.1, and Child1.2

---

> Consider the example that I have in this [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hierarchical-dependency-injection-explained).

Here we have two Component Hierarchies(Main 1 and Main 2). Both Main1 and Main2 have added the `SharedService` to the `providers` array of their `@Component` Decorator Metadata.

Due to this, Main 1 and its Children will have **it's own** instance of the `SharedService`. And Main 2 and its Children will have its own instance of the `SharedService`. These two instances would **NOT BE SAME**.

That's the reason why only the Main1 and its Children's message change when I click the first Button that says: *Change the SharedData - This will only change the SharedData for Main 1 and it's Children*

And same would be the case with Button 2 as it will only update the Contents of Main 2 and it's Children.

Hope this explanation helps. Do have a look at the Sample StackBlitz and it will be more clear.

Comment: Do I then need to import SharedService any where else? Like in app.module? I tried this but I am still getting an error, I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: That would depend on where you want to use the SharedService. Let me update the answer with a Sample Stackblitz to help you understand in a better way.

Comment: Thank you very much